# Obtain one number from numpy subarrays given its peer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array with pairs of numbers (subarrays of size 2) like this:

```
pairs = np.array([[1, 2],[5, 12],[9, 33],[9, 1],[34,7]])
```

and the peers array, like this:

```
nums = np.array([1,12,9])
```

What I want to do is recover the peers of the numbers contained in the num array. The result should be

```
result = np.array([2, 5, 33, 9, 1])
```

**How can I achieve this using numpy functions?** What I am now using is the lazy comparing (actually using lists), for each element in nums array I check if it is contained in any subarray and I store the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the order of the elements doesn't matter, you can easily use:

```python
>>> np.concatenate((pairs[:,1][np.in1d(pairs[:,0], nums)], 
                    pairs[:,0][np.in1d(pairs[:,1], nums)]))
array([ 2, 33,  1,  5,  9])
```

**EDIT:**

To conserve the order, you can use [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
>>> pairs[np.in1d(pairs, nums).reshape((pairs.shape[0],2))[:,[1,0]]]
array([ 2,  5, 33,  9,  1])
```

Comment: I am testing your answer :)

Comment: I'll test later how it works. For now this feature is not important, but as I am checking this with an older code, maybe I can use the ordered result for something useful. I need something which preserves execution speed, that's my priority.